# Как воспринимается в сегодняшнем носителем языка слово "автомашина"?

Tags: лексикон

Иногда, скорее в старших источниках, встречаю слово "автомашина", полагаю что его значение это просто "машина", или "автомобиль". Можно сказать, что слово "автомашина" устаревшее? Как оно звучит уху современного человека? Можно его использовать, хотя бы в шутку?

Comment: Примерно как сегодняшний носитель не назовет аэропорт аэродромом, но прекрасно поймет, о чем идет речь.

Comment: У меня с этим словом ассоциируется грузовик из черно-белого фильма 1950-60-х гг. и шофёр в кепке.

Comment: Аэропорт и аэродром, по-моему, разные вещи.  Оба эти понятия есть в современном языке.

Answer (score 3):

Слово "автомашина" воспринимается как довольно редко употребимое, но вместе с тем не ассоциируется с каким-то определённым историческим периодом, поэтому устарело не звучит.

Было бы здорово, если бы для полноты вопроса вы бы привели примеры такого использования. Вся штука в том, что **частота использования `автомашина` никогда не была сопоставима с частотой использования слова `автомобиль`** - вы можете обратиться к google ngram и увидеть такой график:

[image]

То есть даже в период когда слово `автомашина` использовалось чаще, разрыв был в 10 раз. 
Тут разумеется строгий читатель может сказать, что возможно корпус текстов, который индексирован в гугловом проекте неполный, но мы можем проверить и по национальному корпусу русского языка.

[Вот](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E0%E2%F2%EE%EC%E0%F8%E8%ED%E0) слово `автомобиль`:

[image]

[Вот](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E0%E2%F2%EE%EC%E0%F8%E8%ED%E0) автомашина:
[image]

Comment: Нужно использовать лексико-грамматический поиск, а не точный. Там, правда, всё равно разница примерно в 12 раз, хотя вокруг 1950-го года частота примерно одинаковая.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не очень понимаю его релевантности для моего вопроса. Есть разница в частоте использования и том, звучит-ли слово устарело. Слово может употребляться относительно очень редко, а притом  звучат неф устарело. Более того, сегодня используется чаще всего слово "машина", а не автомобиль, так что нужно было бы такой график привести, если бы слово "машина" не имело и других значений.

Comment: @wondering - это слово воспринимается как довольно редко употребимое но не ассоциируется с каким-то определённым историческим периодом, поэтом устарело не звучит. "Машина" и "автомашина" - разные слова.

Comment: @shabunc Относительно ""Машина" и "автомашина" - разные слова." - все слова разные. Слова "Машина" и "автомашина" одинаковые в том смысле, что оба используются для названия одной и той же вещи. Не хотите добавить "воспринимается как довольно редко употребимое но не ассоциируется с каким-то определённым историческим периодом, поэтом устарело не звучит." в свой ответ? Это же был главный вопрос.

Comment: @wondering да, добавил первым абзацем в общем-то то, что по сути является ответом.

Comment: слово "автомашина" можно услышать в старых фильмах, поэтому и с определённым историческим периодом связать его можно

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка тут уместна была бы ссылка на такой фильм

Comment: не вижу необходимости, так как не намерен что-либо доказывать

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка ок, тогда  я утверждаю - слово "автомобиль" можно услышать в старых фильмах

Comment: можно..........

Answer (score 2):

Для моего уха, как носителя, звучит старомодно. Разве что в шутку или иронично можно использовать при условии, что собеседнику понятен оттенок.

Что касается статуса устаревшего, то тут, наверное, нужно полагаться на авторитет словарей. Если соответствующая помета стоит, значит устаревшее (хотя, насколько я осведомлён, единых критериев устаревания нет). В онлайн версиях словарей такая помета не стоит. Но из активной лексики оно, по-моему, исчезло.